# django import forms basic doubt

Tags: django, django-forms

I have seen people writing forms in models or in `forms.py`? Is it the case I can actually write it anywhere say in `blah.py` and just import it wherever necessary?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's correct. It's just like any other python class, you can define your form classes in whichever file you prefer. However, it is often considered best practice for Django to put them in a file like `APP/forms.py`.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can put it anywhere provided that you can import it

Comment: That's quite vague. How do you know whether you can import it?

Answer (score 0):

You can, but it's better to put forms declarations in forms.py in order that other developers could feel familiar in your project.